# Still getting email for discontinued support of Global HTTP Batch Endpoints

Tags: google-api, gmail-api

I have migrated my Gmail API batch calls to use the new endpoint:

https://www.googleapis.com/batch/gmail/v1

however, I'm still getting emails from Google saying I'm using the API version
gmail@v1 with Global HTTP Batch Endpoint

Is there something else in the url or raw batch request that might be triggering these emails?

Comment: Can you share one of those emails? The email is supposed to list the API calls and projects affected by this.

Comment: I put those details in the question above, but here is a screenshot https://i.imgur.com/DQlccjx.jpg